# Calculating Prediction Intervals

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, regression, prediction

Example Dataframe:

```
new_host  split     sequence    expression
FALSE     train     AQVPYGVS    0.039267878
FALSE     train     ASVPYGVSI   0.039267878
FALSE     train     STNLYGSGR   0.261456561
FALSE     valid     NLYGSGLVR   0.265188519
FALSE     valid     SLGPSNLYG   0.419680588
FALSE     valid     ATSLGTTNG   0.145710993
```

I am trying to calculate the conformal predictions of my model (**PLS Regression Model**), this is based on calculating the prediction intervals (target is the expression of my sequences) based on the conformal function on my calibration data. Basing my algorithm on the following:

[image]

Basically I have:

1. Divided my datasets
2. Fit my model to the training data
3. Defined my conformity function as the absolute error between predicted and true labels
4. Applied the conformity function to my calibration dataset
5. Calculated my conformity sores from step 4

Now I need to determine the prediction intervals based on a significance level. I am having issues when calculating the intervals of my dataset. I keep running into different numpy errors and I am not sure on how to proceed in this case found in my last class method called **conformal_predictions**. Where is I calculate my prediction intervals.

Below is a fragment of my code and I hope this is not too vague, I can still provide additional information if needed.

```
def data_split(df):
    train = df.loc[df['split'] == 'train']
    valid = df.loc[df['split'] == 'valid']
    X_test = valid.iloc[:,:-1]
    y_test = valid.iloc[:,-1] 
    X_train = train.iloc[:,:-1] 
    y_train = train.iloc[:,-1] 
    X_train, X_cal, y_train, y_cal = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size =0.2)
    print("Data has been split")
    print("X_train and y_train shape: "+ str(X_train.shape) + str(y_train.shape))
    print("X_cal and y_cal shape: "+ str(X_cal.shape) + str(y_cal.shape))
    print('{} instances, {} features, {} classes'.format(y_train.size,
                                                   X_train.shape[1],
                                                   np.unique(y_train).size))
    return X_test, y_test, X_train, y_train, X_cal, y_cal
```

My `NonConformistClass`:

```
class NonConformist():

def __init__(self, model):
    self.model = model

def underlying_fit (self, X_train, y_train):
    '''
        Train underlying model on proper training data
        
        @Params
        X_train: has shape (n_train, n_features)
        y_train: has shape (n_train)
    '''
    
    self.model.fit(X_train,y_train)
    print("Model has been fitted")
    
def calibration_predictions(self, X_cal):
    '''
        Obtain predictions from the underlying model using X_cal data. 
        Returns an output of predicted real values as numpy.array of shape (n_test)
        
    @params
    X_cal: numpy array has shape (n_train, n_features)
    '''
    calibration_predictions = self.model.predict(X_cal)

    print("Calibration Predictions Established")
    return calibration_predictions
            
def test_predictions(self, X_test):
    '''
        Obtain predictions from the underlying model using X_test data. 
        Returns an output of predicted real values as numpy.array of shape (n_test)
        
    @params
    X_test: numpy array has shape (n_train, n_features)
    '''
    test_predictions = self.model.predict(X_test)

    print("Calibration Predictions Established")
    return test_predictions
  
def calibration_scores(calibration_predictions, y_cal):
    '''
    Calculates absolute error nonconformity for calibration set.
   For each correct output in ``y``, nonconformity is defined as
   math::
   | y_i (predicted labels) - y^_i (true labels)|     
   
   @params
    true_labels is a numpy array of (true) labels 
    predictions is a numpy array of predicted labels'''
           
    true_labels = np.array(y_cal)
    
    calibration_scores = np.abs(calibration_predictions - true_labels)
    calibration_scores = np.sort(calibration_scores)[::-1] #sort in descending order
    print("Calibration Scores Obtained")
    
    return calibration_scores

def partial_inverse(self, calibration_scores, significance):
    ''' 
    This function is the partial inverse of the nonconformity function (calibration_scores) in order to
    calculate the prediction intervals where:
    
    apply_inverse(...)[0] is subtracted from the prediction of the
            underlying model to create the lower boundary of the
            prediction interval
        apply_inverse(...)[1] is added to the prediction of the
            underlying model to create the upper boundary of the
            prediction interval
    
    @params
    Significance is a float between 0-1 (i.e. 0.05)
    '''
    
    border = int(np.floor(significance * (calibration_scores.size + 1))) - 1
    border = min(max(border, 0), calibration_scores.size - 1)
    
    return np.vstack([calibration_scores[border], calibration_scores[border]])

def conformal_predictions(self, X_test, calibration_scores, significance, test_predictions):
    """This function creates the prediction intervals based from a set of test examples.
    This takes the predictions for each test pattern with the underlying model
    and applies the conformity function to each prediction, resulting in 
    a final prediction interval for each test pattern. 
    
    Predicts the output of each test pattern using the underlying model,
    and applies the (partial) inverse nonconformity function to each
    prediction, resulting in a prediction interval for each test pattern.
    
    @params
    ----------
    X_test: consists of a numpy array of shape [n_samples, n_features]

    significance level : is a float between 0 and 1; determimned as 
    the maximum allowed error rate of predictions.
    
    Returns
    -------
    p : numpy array of shape [n_samples, 2] or [n_samples, 2, 99]
    If significance is ``None``, then p contains the interval (minimum
    and maximum boundaries) for each test pattern, and each significance
    level (0.01, 0.02, ..., 0.99). 
           
    If significance value is a float between
    0 and 1, then p contains the prediction intervals (minimum and
    maximum boundaries) for the set of test patterns at the chosen
    significance level.
    """
    n_test = X_test.shape[0]
    prediction = self.model.predict(x)
    norm = np.ones(n_test)

    if significance:
        intervals = np.zeros((x.shape[0], 2)) #creates empty 2D numpy array
        err_dist = self.err_func.partial_inverse(calibration_scores, significance)
        err_dist = np.hstack([err_dist] * n_test)
        err_dist *= norm

        intervals[:, 0] = test_predictions - err_dist[0, :]
        intervals[:, 1] = test_predictions + err_dist[1, :]

        return intervals
    
    else:
        significance = np.arange(0.01, 1.0, 0.01)
        intervals = np.zeros((x.shape[0], 2, significance.size))

        for i, s in enumerate(significance):
            err_dist = self.err_func.apply_inverse(nc, s)
            err_dist = np.hstack([err_dist] * n_test)
            err_dist *= norm

            intervals[:, 0, i] = prediction - err_dist[0, :]
            intervals[:, 1, i] = prediction + err_dist[0, :]

        return intervals
```

Comment: Please notice that "*I keep running into different numpy errors*" without reference to any specific one is hardly helpful for potential respondents willing to help. Please do take some time to read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as why [a wall of code isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/).

Comment: @desertnaut thank you, I'll revise my answer. I am still new to this forum and trying to figure out it's use